# Geocoding Address Not Returning Correct Coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, clgeocoder

I am trying to get coordinates from address strings and place markers on my map view but I'm not getting the correct coordinates from the geocoder. There are a couple of problems I'm seeing.

One, the annotation on the map are not where they should be, hence not getting the correct coordinates form my geocoder. They should all be fairly close together, but they aren't.

Two, there should be three annotations but only two are showing up. Am I doing something wrong?

My full method. My database currently has latitude and longitude in it but I'm trying to avoid having that in there if I can get this working.

```
func checkDistanceAndAddPins() {
        for gym in gyms {
            var index = 0

            let gymLatitude = gym["latitude"]!!.doubleValue
            let gymLongitude = gym["longitude"]!!.doubleValue
            let gymLocation = CLLocation(latitude: gymLatitude, longitude: gymLongitude)
            let distance = gymLocation.distanceFromLocation(myLocation!)
            let distanceInMeters = NSNumber(double: distance)
            let metersDouble = distanceInMeters.doubleValue
            let miles = metersDouble * 0.00062137

            if miles > maxDistance {
                gyms.removeAtIndex(index)
            } else {
                // let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: gymLatitude, longitude: gymLongitude)
                gymAnnotation = GymAnnotation()
                gymAnnotation!.title = gym["name"] as? String
                gymAnnotation!.subtitle = gym["address"] as? String

                let addressString = gym["address"] as? String
                print("Address: \(addressString)")

                let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
                geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString!, completionHandler: {
                    (placemarks, error) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error", error)
                    }
                    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                        print(placemark.location!.coordinate)
                        self.gymAnnotation!.coordinate = placemark.location!.coordinate
                    }
                })

                // gymAnnotation!.coordinate = location
                gymAnnotation!.gymPhoneNumber = gym["phone"] as? String
                gymAnnotation!.gymID = gym["id"] as? String
                if let website = gym["website"] as? String {
                    gymAnnotation!.gymWebsite = website
                }
                gymLocations.append(gymAnnotation!)
            }

            index += 1
        }

        if self.gymLocations.count == 0 {
            let messageString = String(format: "There are no gyms within %.0f miles of your current location. Try changing the search radius.", maxDistance)
            let noGymsAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: messageString, preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
                (action) -> Void in
                noGymsAlert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            })

            let radiusAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Change Radius", style: .Default, handler: {
                (action) -> Void in
                noGymsAlert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                self.changeSearchDistance()
            })

            noGymsAlert.addAction(radiusAction)
            noGymsAlert.addAction(okAction)
            noGymsAlert.view.tintColor = BarItems.greenTintColor

            self.presentViewController(noGymsAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        for item in gymLocations {
            print("gymLocations Coordinates: \(item.coordinate)")
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.gymMap.addAnnotations(self.gymLocations)
            self.gymMap.showAnnotations(self.gymMap.annotations, animated: true)
            for item in self.gymMap.annotations {
                print("annotations: \(item.coordinate)")
            }
        }
    }
```

My print statement results:

```
Address: Optional("1753 Bardstown Rd, Louisville, KY 40205")
Address: Optional("8609 Westport Rd, Louisville, KY 40205")
Address: Optional("Mid City Mall, 1250 Bardstown Rd, Louisville, KY 40204")
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.235615099999997, longitude: -85.716183599999994)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.22886264358975, longitude: -85.70138458380427)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.281753100000003, longitude: -85.593839399999993)
```

Added print statement to print coordinates for each item in gymLocations:

```
gymLocations Coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
gymLocations Coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
gymLocations Coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
```

And added print statement to right after showAnnotations()

```
annotations: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
annotations: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
annotations: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.21228, longitude: -85.679669000000004)
annotations: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
```

Comment: My guess: `geocodeAddressString()` is async. So for example, if you put a log in it, logging for example when you append the annotation to `gymLocations` and the on when you `showAnnations()` you'll see.

Comment: @Larme see the update to my question.

Comment: The question is: In what order do you see the logs appears? I still think that your issue is about async.

Comment: the geocoder placemarks are appearing last.

Comment: I've updated my question with my full method. I forgot that I was checking distance from the user's location so I will probably need to move the geocoder portion.

Comment: I think that you are still missing the async issue. Look when is called `print(placemark.location!.coordinate)` and when is called `self.gymMap.showAnnotations(self.gymMap.annotations, animated: true)`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by moving all of the code inside the for loop to the geocoder completion handler